# Cassandra Schema Design - Handling Merging of Similar but Differing Source Data Sets

Tags: cassandra

I'm working on a project to merge data from multiple database tables and files into cassandra. This will come from different sources such as flat files, sql db's, etc.

Problem Statement: Most of these source files are similar, however, there are some differences and I want to merge each of these into a single cassandra table. There are about 50 similar fields and an extra 20 fields that don't coexist. My thought is that I can merge them all and just add all of the fields and leave them as tombstones if not populated. The other option would be to merge the same fields into cassandra and then for the fields that are different to add a map column; however, I don't know if there is really any benefit in doing this other than looking nicer.

Any ideas/advice from people who have dealt with this?

Comment: How are you loading the data into database?

Answer (score 0):

What you need is an ETL tool (Extract/Transform/Load) to combine, clean and or standardize the data, and use Cassandra as your repository. There are multiple tools in the market that can provide you this functionality, (a google search for "ETL tools" can give you an overwhelming amount of resources to choose from).

As a personal preference check https://nifi.apache.org/ , you can define those transformations and filtering as workflows

Comment: The issue isn't the merging of data, I already do this for other datasets. I'm trying to figure out the best way to merge multiple datasets into a single table for the purpose of analysis. Yes, I could simply create multiple tables, one for each source, but that gets messy.